# Adding interactive user input e.g., `read` in a Docker container

Tags: linux, bash, docker, stdin

I want to make a Docker image that can perform the following:

1. Get user input and store it in a local variable using `read`
2. Utilize that variable for a later command

Using that I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN ["echo", "'Input something: '"]
RUN ["read", "some_var"]
RUN ["echo", "You wrote $some_var!"]
```

which, when running `docker build`, yields the following output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/4 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> 4e2eef94cd6b
Step 2/4 : RUN ["echo", "'Input something: '"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a9d967721ade
Step 3/4 : RUN ["read", "some_var"]
 ---> Running in e1c603e2d376
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"read\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

`read` seems to be a built-in bash "function" since `which read` yields nothing.
I replaced `["read", "some_var"]` with `["/bin/bash -c read", "some_var"]` and `["/bin/bash", "-c", "read", "some_var"]` but both yield the following:

```
...
Step 3/4 : RUN ["/bin/bash -c read", "some_var"]
 ---> Running in 6036267781a4
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash -c read\": stat /bin/bash -c read: no such file or directory": unknown
```

```
...
Step 3/4 : RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "read", "some_var"]
 ---> Running in 947dda3a9a6c
The command '/bin/bash -c read some_var' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

In addition, I also replaced it with `RUN read some_var` but which yields the following:

```
...
Step 3/4 : RUN read some_var
 ---> Running in de0444c67386
The command '/bin/sh -c read some_var' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to **use an external shell script** and use [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint).

Contents of `run.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Input something!"
read some_var
echo "You wrote ${some_var}!"
```

Contents of `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu
COPY "run.sh" .
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./run.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT [ "./run.sh" ]
```

This will allow `./run.sh` to run when the container is spun:

```
$ docker build -t test .
Step 1/4 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> 4e2eef94cd6b
Step 2/4 : COPY "run.sh" .
 ---> 37225979730d
Step 3/4 : RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./run.sh"]
 ---> Running in 5f20ded00739
Removing intermediate container 5f20ded00739
 ---> 41174edb932c
Step 4/4 : ENTRYPOINT [ "./run.sh" ]
 ---> Running in bed7717c1242
Removing intermediate container bed7717c1242
 ---> 554da7be7972
Successfully built 554da7be7972
Successfully tagged test:latest

$ docker run -it test
Input something!
Test message 
You wrote Test message!
```

Comment: (Remember that running `docker` commands will often require `sudo` permission – you can almost trivially use it to root the host – and the container won't have access to the user's home directory or other content.  Just running `./run.sh` without Docker will be easier.)

Comment: What do you mean? While `run.sh` in this case is a trivial stdin+stdout operation, that may not be the case for more complex operations that would need containerization. Also I am using rootless docker in my environment but wouldn't a root user be able to access all of the system's files?

Comment: Not without special configuration: try `docker run --rm -it -u root alpine sh` to get an interactive root shell in a debugging container and see what you can and can't see.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, this creates a new from the Alpine image as root. I don't expect any of the files in my home folder in my host to be available for use, unless if I were to do some binding. In my Dockerfile though I used a `COPY` operation such that I expect a local file in the same folder named `run.sh` available for use in the image.

A bit of clarification since I wrote that late at night: when I said "wouldn't a root user be able to access all of the system's files", I meant the root user running Docker (`sudo docker [cmd...]`). That's not relevant at all I think, sorry for the confusion.